# React Native - Storybook Adding Addons

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I am using a boilerplate [Ignite Bowser](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite-bowser) and I am trying to add Knob Addon to storybook, but so far I cant make it to work.

On the story, I added a decorator like the following code:

> storiesOf("Button", module)
> .addDecorator(fn => {fn()})
> .addDecorator(withKnobs)

However, when trying to add: "@storybook/addon-knobs/register" Im failing at it.
Some help would be nice.

Thanks

[Project Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFMFh.png)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? kindly share

Comment: For anyone else who might get here, just so you know, `@storybook/addon-knobs` have since been deprecated and you should opt for the `@storybook/addon-controls` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When running on React Native you need to install knobs from the on-device

1. Create a file named ./rn-addons.ts
2. Add the following import on the file:

   `import '@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs/register'`
3. Then in your file storybook.ts, you import that rn-addons:

   `import './rn-addons'`